# Angular 3D Carousel - Autoslide after delay is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular1.6

I am using the Angular 3-D Carousel Libray and trying to implement the autoslide feature. However it doesn't work. Please check the codepen below:

https://codepen.io/Wlada/pen/QdPvjp

```js
 vm.options = {
    sourceProp: 'src',
    visible: 5,
    perspective: 35,
    startSlide: 0,
    border: 3,
    dir: 'ltr',
    width: 360,
    height: 270,
    space: 220,
    loop: true,
    clicking: true
  };
```

I have updated the option "Loop" to true.

Answer (score 0):

Had to add `autoRotationSpeed: 2500, loop: true,only` to the options to get the auto-slide feature working

In your existing codepen, make sure that your **JS part** is as follows:

```
angular
  .module('demo', [
    'ngSanitize',
    'angular-carousel-3d'
  ])
  .controller('AppController', AppController);

AppController.$inject = ['$scope', '$log'];

function AppController($scope, $log) {
  var vm = this;

  // SLIDES WITH CAPTIONS
  //===================================
  vm.slides = [{
    'src': 'http://vladimirbujanovic.com/angular-carousel-3d/demo/images/photo2.jpg',
    caption: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, maxime.'
  }, {
    'src': 'http://vladimirbujanovic.com/angular-carousel-3d/demo/images/photo3.jpg',
    caption: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet '
  }, {
    'src': 'http://vladimirbujanovic.com/angular-carousel-3d/demo/images/photo4.jpg',
    caption: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. '
  }, {
    'src': 'http://vladimirbujanovic.com/angular-carousel-3d/demo/images/photo5.jpg',
    caption: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  Enim, maxime.'
  }, {
    'src': 'http://vladimirbujanovic.com/angular-carousel-3d/demo/images/photo6.jpg',
    caption: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, maxime.'
  }];

  vm.options = {
    sourceProp: 'src',
    visible: 5,
    perspective: 35,
    startSlide: 0,
    border: 3,
    dir: 'ltr',
    width: 360,
    height: 270,
    space: 220,
    clicking: true,
    autoRotationSpeed: 2500,
    loop: true
  };

  // ANY HTML
  //===================================
  vm.slides2 = [{
    'bg': '#2a6496',
    caption: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, maxime.'
  }, {
    'bg': '#000000',
    caption: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet '
  }, {
    'bg': '#ffcc41',
    caption: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. '
  }, {
    'bg': '#445fac',
    caption: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  Enim, maxime.'
  }, {
    'bg': '#442BF3',
    caption: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  Maxime.'
  }];

  vm.options2 = {
    visible: 3,
    perspective: 35,
    startSlide: 0,
    border: 0,
    dir: 'ltr',
    width: 360,
    height: 270,
    space: 220,
    autoRotationSpeed: 2500,
    loop: true,
    controls: true
  };

  vm.removeSlide = removeSlide;
  vm.addSlide = addSlide;
  vm.selectedClick = selectedClick;
  vm.slideChanged = slideChanged;
  vm.beforeChange = beforeChange;
  vm.lastSlide = lastSlide;

  function lastSlide(index) {
    $log.log('Last Slide Selected callback triggered. \n == Slide index is: ' + index + ' ==');
  }

  function beforeChange(index) {
    $log.log('Before Slide Change callback triggered. \n == Slide index is: ' + index + ' ==');
  }

  function selectedClick(index) {
    $log.log('Selected Slide Clicked callback triggered. \n == Slide index is: ' + index + ' ==');
  }

  function slideChanged(index) {
    $log.log('Slide Changed callback triggered. \n == Slide index is: ' + index + ' ==');
  }

  function addSlide(slide, array) {
    array.push(slide);
    vm.slide2 = {};
  }

  function removeSlide(index, array) {
    array.splice(array.indexOf(array[index]), 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Added autorotationspeed and it started working.

Comment: you're welcome, i'd appreciate if you accept the answer and give a vote up, Thanks.